# How to set the timezone during an Automated Install of 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, cloud-init

I'm installing 20.04 with an [Automated Server Install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls), but I can't see where to put the timezone?

By default it is installing as `Etc/UTC` but I want something else.

After installing I checked `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data` and there doesn't seem to be a timezone entry.

And the [config reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls/ConfigReference) doesn't mention timezones either.

Answer (score 9):

The Ubuntu [Automated Server Installs Config File Reference](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference) describes the cloud-init user-data top level key.

**timezone** is supported in the user-data [timezone module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#timezone) which is documented further in the cloud-init docs.

```
user-data:
  timezone: Pacific/Auckland
```

From [Discourse - Please Test Autoinstalls Post #85](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-test-autoinstalls-for-20-04/15250/85)

Answer (score 3):

Try a [late command](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls/ConfigReference#late-commands)

> **late-commands**
>  
>   type: command list
>   default: no
>   commands can be interactive: no
>
> Shell commands to run after the install has completed successfully and
>   any updates and packages installed, just before the system reboots.
>   They are run in the installer environment with the installed system
>   mounted at /target. You can run `curtin in-target -- $shell_command`
>   (with the version of subiquity released with 20.04 GA you need to
>   specify this as `curtin in-target --target=/target -- $shell_command`)
>   to run in the target system (similar to how plain in-target can be
>   used in d-i preseed/late_command).

Example:

`curtin in-target --target=/target -- timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and attempted the late command however after booting the installed system the clock remained GMT. The "timedatectl set" only worked for me after the system was installed and not through the automated install process. I substituted the timedatectl command with the following command and was able to get my clock switched to my local timezone:

curtin in-target --target=/target -- cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime